# How do I answer the third question correctly when I am gaining large numbers of candies?

Tags: candy-box-2

How can I get the right answer to the 3rd squirrel question ("how many candies" etc.), as I am gaining 21 of them each second and I am not very good at mental calculus? ;)

Comment: ...addition is hardly calculus.

Comment: Type in a number that is 210 more than your current total of candies (assuming you can type that number in less than 10 seconds).  Wait until the number of candies matches what you typed.  Submit answer.

Comment: @Doorknob: Off-topic, but: "calculus" refers to any system for doing calculations.  Colloquially, "Calculus" is actually short for differential/integral calculus, but there are [many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) [other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) [calculuses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_calculus).  Cadiest's usage of the term is correct.

Answer (score 3):

If you got as far as the lollipop-farm, and you have the lolligaters, you can make them change your candy into lollipops faster than you can earn, and eat all your candy. Now the amount of candy you have is zero!